# In-App-Purchase subscribed state in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

So I have a question about doing an in-app purchase with a subscription in swift. I read at this link: https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-subscription-testing-on-ios#sandbox that you need your app to enter subscribed state. Is this some kind of delegate method or something I call, or does it simply mean that I enable the features? I haven't been able to find much detail on that part. Any guidance would be much appreciated. I do have the in-app purchase dialog appearing and the sandbox account working. I also get the alert saying the purchase was a successful. But even 2 seconds later if I try again it just allows me to purchase again.

Answer (score 0):

By *subscribed state* they mean that a user still should have access to the content he unlocked with the subscription.

> But even 2 seconds later if I try again it just allows me to purchase again.

Unfortunately, it is your responsibility to hide already bought in-app purchases from your users. Although, Apple prevents buying the same subscription again. So, when your first purchases succeeded, the second one should lead to an alert from Apple, that the purchases weren't executed. Otherwise, I assume your purchase logic is faulty.

How do you check the eligibility of your users? Do you validate the receipt locally, or are you using RevenueCat for that?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I've got it figured out now. I added the paymentQueue(updatedTransactions) method from the SKPaymentTransactionObserver in the AppDelegate and now I am at least getting an alert stating I already purchased. I think I can do the rest from here.